# $stateParams for logged user and all user

Tags: angularjs, ui-sref

I have dashboard, where i am a super admin. I create user profile, where I can see all my profile data. Now, i have table of all users, and i want to open and, if need, edit user profile for some user. 
Here is html code for call user profile () for logged user

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm" ui-sref="user-profile/:userID">{{'USER_PROFILE'| translate}}</a>
```

And here is ctrl where i call state params

```
.controller('userProfileCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', '$http','userProfileFactory',
 function ($scope, $stateParams, $state, $http, userProfileFactory) {
 $scope.authentication = authService.authentication;
$scope.userID = $scope.authentication.userID;
$stateParams.userID = $scope.userID;
$scope.user = userProfileFactory.get({user: $stateParams.userID});
  $scope.user.$promise.then(function (data){
     console.log(data.id);
     return data;
 });
```

Now i want to select in table some user and open his profile

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users|filter:f" such-href="user-profile/{{user.id}}">
```

And call some user profile with this ctrl

```
$http.get(serviceBase + 'users/'+ $stateParams.userID +'/aaaa/').success (function(data){
            $scope.media = data.media;
            });
```

And here is ui-state

```
.state('user-profile/:userID', {
                url: '/user-profile/:userID',
                templateUrl: 'aaaa/aaa/aaaae/user-profile.html',
                controller: 'aaaaCtrl'
            })
```

Problem is, any time I open user profile, I get my data in profile (super admin data).

Answer (score 0):

I set $rootScope for the user_id to get it for global use. Now when you start the app you get the logged user.

```
$scope.authentication = authService.authentication;
$rootScope.user_id = $scope.authentication.userID;
$scope.user = userProfileFactory.get({user: $stateParams.userID});
 $scope.user.$promise.then(function (data){
     return data;
 });
```

Now use this in html.

```
such-href="user-profile/{{user_id}}.
```

Now you have the logged user.

To get the admin open the user profile like we did before but use :USERID in factory instead.

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users|filter:f" such-href="user-profile/{{user.id}}">
```